# GPO not applying on a Windows 2012 R2 Terminal Server with Citrix VDA

Tags: windows, group-policy, xenapp

We have a Citrix XenApp environment. In the environment we mostly use Server 2012 R2 as Terminal Servers and have a domain running on 2k8 R2. Now I want to configure Folder Redirection. 
Therefore I created an OU and moved the Terminalservers in there and also created a group for the users that shall get their Folders redirected. 
I also have a Fileserver set up for the roaming profiles and the Folder Redirection. Permissions are fine (followed the guidelines for Folder Redirection). 
Then I created the GPO for the Terminalserver-OU and set the settings for Folder Redirection.

The problem is that the GPO does not get applied at all. I ran gpresult and I can't see the GPO at all. It is also missing from the Denied GPOs. I also turned debugging on gpupdate on, but there is also no trace of my GPO in the log.

Further information: 
- WMI Filtering is turned off
- There is a "Citrix Group Policy" applying, although there are no Policies for this delivery group

Has anybody an idea?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

The users and the GPO have to be in the same OU, since the Folder Redirection settings are User Configuration. I now linked the GPO in the Terminalserver OU and the User OU and everything works as expected. The Computer Configuration part from the GPO enables the roaming profiles only on the Terminal Servers and the User Configuration is configured to only enable for the users where the GPO is linked and only if they are connected to the TS.

You may have to edit your existing GPOs to make sure that you don't affect your regular client devices with the new TS GPO.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Loopback policy processing instead of moving the users.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2013/02/08/circle-back-to-loopback.aspx